# how to fix a menu at the top opf the form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, menu

I am developing the application using VB.Net, in that i am using the menu. but the menu is not visible when the form is scrolled down. how can i fix it?

Comment: Things that should scroll should be in a container, such as a Panel control.  Things that should not scroll should not be in that container.  Move your scrolling logic and controls to a Panel control and do not include your ToolStrip control in that container, keep it outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [Dock property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
MyMenuControl.Dock = DockStyle.Top
```

*"Gets or sets which control borders are docked to its parent control and determines how a control is resized with its parent."*

Comment: But if we scroll the window then it will goes up. so didn't visible to us.